# Windows - Can mist be used from the command line?

Tags: mist, windows, command-line

I see that mist can be used from the command line in Linux, but the `mist` and/or `ethereumwallet` commands don't work in PowerShell or even Git bash in Windows. Is there any way to use Mist from the command line?

Comment: What do you mean it can be used with command line? Mist is an interface using geth. Geth is command line, not mist.

Comment: @Andromelus mist is a web browser interface that can run on top of a client like geth. Can mist be run from the command line?

Comment: Mist is an electron application, means it's a **desktop hybrid application with a web interface**.  You can run mist from windows command line, it's also support some options I assume. What are you trying to achive?

Comment: @Зелёный I'm trying to find the command for running mist from the command line on Windows.

Comment: I assume something like this should work `start C:\PATH_TO_FORLDER\mist.exe`

Comment: @Зелёный I guess that's all there is. I was assuming that there was a PATH binding or something like that, like there is on Linux.

Comment: You dont need `PATH` if you're specifing full path to the executable, as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Install your computer Geth https://geth.ethereum.org/ and Install mkdir directory use to cmd 
example: C:\Program Files\Geth

Then you save this file to any drive on your computer
File name / genesis.json

```
{
    "nonce"     : "0x0000000000000055",
    "mixHash"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "difficulty": "0x20000",
    "gasLimit"  : "0x800000",
    "timestamp" : "0x0",
    "extraData" : "",
    "coinbase"  : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc"     : {},
    "config"    : {
        "chainId": 100,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    }
}
```

Then geth file directory and command run 
example :

```
geth --datadir "D:\bolckchain\chaindata" init "c\genesis.json"
```

[image]

then command run:

```
>geth attach
```

[image]

```
>admin
```

Then Windows command run Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like Зелёный mentioned in the comments on the question, you'll have to use the full path, along with the `start` command. **Important note:** At least when I was playing with it, the flags (like `-rpc`) will *not* work with PowerShell, though they do work with Git bash.